# How Do You Raise an Event With a Parameter?

Tags: vb.net, events, raiseevent

I've recently started working with C# after working with VB.Net for a while.

In VB.Net you can raise an event with parameters that you pass in.
For example

```
Event TileMoved(ThisTile As Tile)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RaiseEvent TileMoved(Me)
End Sub
```

Please could someone explain how to do this in C#?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this nothing you could google? I mean there is documentation on MSDN explaining how to work with events.

Comment: See [Convert VB to C# or C# to VB](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vb -> c# conversion gives this result.

```
public event TileMovedEventHandler TileMoved;
public delegate void TileMovedEventHandler(Tile ThisTile);

private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (TileMoved != null) {
        TileMoved(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that instead of creating a new delegate you could also just use `Action<Tile>`; or, if you want to seperate between the sender and the actual data send by this event, `EventHandler<Tile>` or `EventHandler<SomeEventArgsThatContainsTile>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event data class. See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can think of events as a method call at an unpredictable time. The rest of the program doesn't really know when something will happen, so methods are 'delegated' to respond to events being raised. The parameters I have expressed here are the Microsoft standard, but you can use any parameters you like.

**However, the method that receives the event MUST have exactly the same parameters as the event being raised.**

Here's how you make events in VB.
In the event declaration:

`Public Event OnLoad(e As System.EventArgs, sender as Object)`

In the event call:
`RaiseEvent OnLoad(New EventArgs(), Me)`

You can use any kind of parameters you want there.

Making a method respond to the event

`Public Sub HelloWorld(e as System.EventArgs, sender as Object) Handles OtherObject.OnLoad`

End Sub

OR:

`AddHandler OtherObject.OnLoad, AddressOf MethodToHandleTheEvent`

Hope this helps. Please comment if you have any more questions.